# How to solve the array initialization issue with visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I want to declare an array as one of the members of the Struct. It fails, the compiler throws the following error:

```
error C2536: ... : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays
```

Here is my struct in .h file:

```
struct CommandRepo
{
    std::string root_command[5] = { "create", "edit", "remove", "list", "setting" };
    std::string Base = "^(create|edit|remove|settings|list)(?: *)(?:--([a-zA-Z]*))";
    std::string EachWord = "(\\w+)";
};
```

It seems (as read somewhere in SO), VSC2013 is not fully compliant with C++11, and the error is associated with that lack of compliance. Is that true? How should I solve it?

Comment: Until Visual Studio gets their act together, you have to do it the old-fasioned way in a constructor. Or you could make it static const, if it never changes.

Comment: You could try the Visual Studio 2015 Preview.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use a `std::vector`? As in:

```
struct CommandRepo
{
    std::vector<std::string> root_command = { "create", "edit", "remove", "list", "setting" };
    std::string Base = "^(create|edit|remove|settings|list)(?: *)(?:--([a-zA-Z]*))";
    std::string EachWord = "(\\w+)";
};
```

The interface to this struct definitely changes, but this lets you initialize a list of `std::string`s.

Comment: Well, it is indeed possible. But since the size of the container is clear and it is fixed, array is a more elegant choice.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi What about `std::array<std::string, 5>`?

Comment: If a regular array didn't work, what makes you think something more complicated would work?

Comment: If you're concerned about improper uses of the `vector`, then you can add a `const` modifier to it. This way, all operations that change the size of the `vector` are caught by the compiler. Currently there's no fixed size STL construct you can use, and your compiler doesn't like arrays, so this seems to be a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @NeilKirk, seems to be more an issue of compiler support than it is of complexity.

Comment: It states in the question it is about compiler support.

Comment: @NeilKirk, indeed. Since this is a question of compiler support, it seems perfectly reasonable to me to ask if a `vector` would work for OP. A `vector` being more complex does not necessarily mean it won't be supported by the compiler. OP indicated with his first comment that this is possible on his compiler, but it doesn't meet his design requirements.